# Large datatable always throwing System.outofmemory exception

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a large datatable which contains around 500 000 rows. I have to iterate through that data table and apply a business logic on each row.
The problem is that when after certain level of iteration over that huge datatable it throws System.OutofMemory exception.

dt is the datatable which contains 500 000 records.
I tried below approach:

```
int pageNum = 1;
int pageSize = 10000;
Datatable dtPage = null;
DataModel model = null;
//DataModel  is a class containing various properties 
//i.e public class DataModel
//{
//  public string Name {get;set;}
 // public string Role {get;set;}
//etc....
//}

while(dt.Rows.Count  - (pageNum * pageSize ) > 0)
{
 dtPage = dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Skip((pageNum -1 ) *   pageSize).CopyToTable();
foreach(DataRow row in dtPage.Rows)
{
model = new DataModel();
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(DataModel).GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
if(dtPage.Columns.Contains(property.Name))
 SetNewValue(model,property.Name,row[property.Name]);
}
if(model! = null) lst.Add(model);
}
pageNum ++;
}
```

What to use in this case? I have also tried batch approach of MoreLinq but still did not had any luck.

Comment: I'd question why you are using a data table to begin with for that many rows, but if you insist on going that route you could always delete the row in the data table after you are done converting it into a model.  You are essentially keeping two copies of a very large set of data in memory.

Comment: Are you loading the datatable from a database or building on the fly?

Comment: @PaulAbbott What would you recommend using for such a large collection of data? Or should they just look into only getting smaller quantities at a time and processing it that way.

Comment: If the data is coming from a database, why not just loop through a datareader, which is much less expensive? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @PaulAbbott,@WiseGod: Actually I am populating datatable to object data model for which I was using reflection. The data is coming from a database and I am loading the data by using data reader only. After that I am using reflection to populate data table to object.

Answer (score 0):

How about this line of code...

```
if(model! = null) lst.Add(model);
```

I would suspect that is your culprit due to the fact that you are continuing to add items to a variable that is outside the scope of your loop (which leads to question, why bother with all the complicated paging logic then if all you are doing is dumping everything into the same list).

You are iterating over a datatable with half a million rows, re-casting it as IEnumerable for every page, using reflection to iterate over your DataModel object, using reflection to set properties, and then storing the new objects in a collection.  Your memory usage will indeed continue to grow as you iterate over the table, because you are creating new objects on every single iteration.

This approach is impractical from both a performance and memory standpoint.  Consider doing the following:

- Cast your datatable to IEnumerable only once and store it in a variable so you aren't recasting every time
- Don't use reflection in a huge loop like this.  I am not anti-reflection, but performance will be abysmal.  Either explicitly write code to populate your object, or consider expression trees (although I believe in this case Expression Trees are overly complex)
- If this is coming from a database, implement paging in your stored procedure or select statement to only pull the data you need for a single page
- If you need to populate everything at once for some reason, then ditch the paging logic since you aren't using it in the code above
- Use a DataReader instead of a DataTable.  A DataReader is faster and has less overhead than a DataTable/DataSet
- Use column indexes, not column names, to retrieve data.  Using the column name vs. the index introduces additional performance penalties.  If you need to do it dynamically, then get the index of the column once using the name, store it, and use the stored value from there out

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations. Let me explain more briefly my problem. I have  a mainframe database from which I am exporting 5 lakh records using ODBC . Now I have to populate the datatable into data model(object). The data model or class has more than 150 properties which needs to be populated from datatable. I am using reflection to do so inside every iteration of each datarow. Please tell me is there any other good or more performance efficient method apart from reflection to do so. (Please note I have more than 150 properties that needs to be populated).

Comment: I'd recommend using PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod, use that MethodInfo to create a delegate, and then cache the delegate for each property.  Instead of using reflection to get the value, you'd call the delegate.  This is a great article on how to do it:

http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can you tell me how to use delegate/reflection concept here especially while populating datatable into model. A small code snippet or example would do a world of help to me as well as other users who will view this link.